# Spring Boot internationalization (messages.properties)

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to simply add the version number of an application to a Thymeleaf fragment.  I'm using Spring Boot 1.2.5.  If I have a file named **/resources/messages.properties** defined like this:

```
application.version=1.0.0
```

And I have a Thymeleaf view with the following fragment:

```
Application Version: <span th:text="#{application.version}">
```

It's displaying something like **??application.version_en_US??** instead of 1.0.0.  (I also have files named **messages_en.properties** and **messages_en_US.properties** in the classpath with the same contents too.)  I am really not sure how to resolve this problem...  I've spent hours on something which seems incredibly trivial...

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.application"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.class})
@PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("classpath:website.properties")})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

**WebConfig.java**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public SpelAwareProxyProjectionFactory projectionFactory() {
    return new SpelAwareProxyProjectionFactory();
}

@Bean
public SessionHandler sessionHandler() {
    return new SessionHandler();
}

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/web/auth/login").setViewName("auth/login");
    registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(
            "/resources/");
}

@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("language");
    return localeChangeInterceptor;
}

@Bean
public CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
    localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    return localeResolver;
}

@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    return new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    // Locale change interceptor
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());

    // Utility interceptor which helps with the "active" link styles in the navigation.  --mm
    registry.addInterceptor(new BaseInterceptor());

    // Expire session after a period of time
    registry.addInterceptor(sessionHandler());
}
}
```

**ThymeleafConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

@Bean
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");

    // must use Legacy HTML5 as the template, otherwise Handlebars will not parse!
    //
    // this should hopefully be fixed in Thymeleaf 3.0
    resolver.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5");
    resolver.setCacheable(false);
    return resolver;
}

public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());

    // Add Spring security
    Set<IDialect> dialects = new HashSet<IDialect>();
    engine.setAdditionalDialects(dialects);
    engine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
    return engine;
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    viewResolver.setOrder(1);
    viewResolver.setViewNames(new String[]{"*"});
    viewResolver.setCache(false);
    return viewResolver;
}
}
```

Will buy a virtual round of shots to whomever can resolve this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you could always add this in your templateEngine method:

```
engine.addMessageResolver(new StandardMessageResolver());
or engine.setMessageResolver(new StandardMessageResolver());
```

Also,from the design perspective,i would suggest you to try using the autoconfiguration for thymeleaf(removing the exclude),and many other stuff which spring boot provides automatically for you.

Comment: I gave up at this home-brewed configuration and just placed all Thymeleaf configuration in application.properties.  i18n now works like a champ.